# Send events to parent statechart in multi state machine modeling in Yakindu

Tags: statechart

I have 2 statecharts, one being the parent and the other being the child. When the parent statechart is created, it also creates a child statechart using

```
import: "Child.ysc"
var child: Child
```

The parent statechart can easily raise an event in the child statechart, for example:

```
raise child.goToD
```

But the problem is that there's no way to reference the same parent in the child statechart to be able to raise an event in the parent. Is there a way to send events to parent statecharts? Or can the child send a reference of itself as an attribute to the parent (for example using *this* in python) which can then save it in a variable to be accessed for sending those events?

PS: both statecharts have the default domain and not the C/C++ domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two approaches.

The first approach is to define an explicit reference from the child statechart to the parent. Like you did for the parent.

```
import: "Parent.ysc"
var parent : Parent
```

Please be aware that you have to set the relation explicitly in your C++ code:

```
child.setParent(&parent);
```

The second approach is to use out events. The child can define out events like:

```
interface:
    out event dReached
```

Raise it somewhere in the child statechart:

```
raise dReached
```

and use the event as a trigger in the parent:

```
child.dReached / doSomething()
```

The generated parent code will care about subscribing and listening to out events emitted by the child.

Mostly I would prefer the second approach. It does not imply bidirectional dependencies between parent and child.