# How can I react to events from a master statechart in Yakindu?

Tags: statechart

I have a statechart that does stuff depending on another statechart. Let's call them Master and Slave.

In the Slave statechart I import the Master and assign it to a variable.

```
import: "Master.ysc"
var master: Master
```

Let's say the Slave statechart is in `StateA` and wants to go to `StateB` when Master triggers an event `B`. Then as a transition trigger I use `master.B`

My problem is that the Slave statechart doesn't see the Master events. In the generated (Python) code `self.master = None` in the init method of the Slave, and it always stays `None`. Is there a way to do this properly?

I also tried to raise an event in the Slave directly from Master, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886808/send-events-to-parent-statechart-in-multi-state-machine-modeling-in-yakindu) question:

```
import: "Slave.ysc"
var slave: Slave

raise slave.goto_b
```

But here I also have a problem with the reference being None.

```
    self.slave.raise_goto_b()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raise_goto_b'
```

Am I missing something simple (an assignment to the master/slave variable or something), or is it a problem with the Python bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was indeed missing an assignment. I should just have tried harder with the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886808/send-events-to-parent-statechart-in-multi-state-machine-modeling-in-yakindu).

So I sent a reference of the Master statemachine to the Slave. In Main:

```
master_fsm = MasterFsm()
slave_fsm = SlaveFsm(master_fsm)
```

The 'Fsms' have an `sm` attribute with the generated class.
So in the SlaveFsm's init method I did:

```
def __init__(self, master_fsm):
    self.sm = Slave()
    self.sm.master = master_fsm.sm
```

And then it works!